# How to crate generalized spring been only once for all cases

Tags: java, spring, generics

I want to create generalized spring been only once for all cases to avoid redundant code duplication. Consider an example where I want one validator for both Login and Purchase events.

Events

```
interface UserEvent {
    int getUserId();
}

@Value
class LoginEvent implements UserEvent {
    int userId;
    long timestamp;
}

@Value
class PurchaseEvent implements UserEvent {
    int userId;
    long transactionId;
}
```

Validator which define if user from event is valid

```
class UserValidator<T extends UserEvent> {

    public T isUserValid(T event) {
        if (event.getUserId() % 3 == 0) {
            return event;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("User with id=%d is invalid", event.getUserId()));
    }
}
```

Context with validators

```
@Configuration
class ValidatorContext {

    @Bean
    public UserValidator<LoginEvent> userValidatorOnLogin() {
        return new UserValidator<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserValidator<PurchaseEvent> userValidatorOnPurchase() {
        return new UserValidator<>();
    }
}
```

Service context

```
@Configuration
class ServiceContext {

    @Bean
    public LoginService loginService(UserValidator<LoginEvent> userValidatorOnLogin) {
        return new LoginService(loginValidator);
    }

    @Bean
    public PurchaseService purchaseService(UserValidator<PurchaseEvent> userValidatorOnPurchase) {
        return new PurchaseService(purchaseValidator);
    }
}
```

The problem here that I forced to create validators for both event types. Is it possible to create validator only once like here?

```
@Configuration
class Context {

    @Bean
    public UserValidator<UserEvent> userValidator() {
        return new UserValidator<>();
    }
}
```

And inject it to the services

```
@Configuration
class ServiceContext {

    @Bean
    public LoginService loginService(UserValidator<LoginEvent> userValidator) {
        return new LoginService(loginValidator);
    }

    @Bean
    public PurchaseService purchaseService(UserValidator<PurchaseEvent> userValidator) {
        return new PurchaseService(purchaseValidator);
    }
}
```

If you paid attention, validator returns original object with a specific type. It's because in business flow (`LoginService` `PurchaseService`) I require this specific type. And it is the main problem. Also the real case is much harder and this example is maximally simplified for understanding the problem. So any refactoring or hints like *'use original object which you use as a parameter for `isUserValid` in your business logic'* will not help.